# Rust - nested loop going only once inside inner loop

Tags: rust

I am taking data from text file

```
let fil1_json = File::open("fil1.json")?;
let mut fil1_json_reader = BufReader::new(fil1_json);

let fil2_json = File::open("fil2.json")?;
let mut fil2_json_reader = BufReader::new(fil2_json);

for fil1_line in fil1_json_reader.by_ref().lines() {
    for fil2_line in fil2_json_reader.by_ref().lines() {
        println!("{:#?} ----- {:#?}", fil1_line, fil2_line);
    }
}
```

In the second nested loop, it is only going inside once. It looks like `fil2_json_reader` is getting emptied after first iteration.

Where it is changing as I am not changing anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where it is changing as I am not changing anywhere?

Readers *consume* the data. In the case of `File`, this is the natural expectation, since file abstractions almost universally have a cursor that advances every time you read.

If you want to iterate several times over the same data, then the obvious option is saving it to memory (typically before splitting into `lines()`, but you can also save a vector of those even if it will be slower). However, since the reader is backed by an actual file, it is better to re-iterate over the file by `seek`ing to its beginning:

```
fil2_json_reader.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))
```

Comment: _since the reader is backed by an actual file, it is better to re-iterate over the file_ → debatable: if the file is small, it is better to read all into a string, and use [`&str::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), which avoids reallocating a new `String` for each line.

Comment: @Jmb There is no need to allocate a string per line. Allocating and copying entire files into memory for no reason is sloppy coding that wastes memory, cache and performance.

Comment: [`BufReader::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) does allocate a `String` for each line whether you want it to or not. If the file is large, that is preferable to storing the whole file in memory, but if the file is small, then avoiding the repeated allocations will be better.

Comment: @Jmb Nobody forces you to use an interface based on `Lines` if you care about performance or memory, which *you* do since that was your comment complained about. Storing the whole file is a waste in both time and space which you cannot afford if you are that concerned about performance or memory. And if you do not care, then your comment is a pointless worry to begin with :)